# expression for$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)(k+2)$

Tags: combinatorics

what is a closed expression for$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)(k+2)$? the answer says to look at Generating function $a_k=(k+1)(k+2)$ and derive twice $\dfrac{1}{x}=1+x+x^2+...$ so the solution starts: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)(k+2)=[\dfrac{1}{(1-x)}.\dfrac{2}{(1-x)^3}]$but isn't $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k=\dfrac{1}{(1-t)}$? so how the lhs and rhs in  $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)(k+2)=[\dfrac{1}{(1-x)}.\dfrac{2}{(1-x)^3}]$ are equal?

Comment: You are forgetting the powers of $t$ in the lhs.

Comment: $$(k+1)(k+2) = \frac{(k+3)-k}{3}(k+1)(k+2) = \frac13\left((k+1)(k+2)(k+3)-k(k+1)k+2)\right)$$

Comment: That is an excellent solution @achillehui

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.** You may want to write

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)(k+2) \right) x^{n} = \frac{2}{(1-x)^{4}}. $$

---

Here is another solution using the Pascal's triangle:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)(k+2) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{k+2}{2} = 2 \left[ \binom{2}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n+2}{2} \right]. $$

Now we know that $\binom{2}{2} = 1 = \binom{3}{3}$. So by applying the property $\binom{m}{k-1} + \binom{m}{k} = \binom{m+1}{k}$ repeatedly, we observe

\begin{align*}
\binom{2}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n+2}{2}
&= \binom{3}{3} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n+2}{2} \\
&= \binom{4}{3} + \binom{4}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n+2}{2} \\
&= \binom{5}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n+2}{2} \\
&\quad \quad \vdots \\
&= \binom{n+2}{3} + \binom{n+2}{2} \\
&= \binom{n+3}{3}.
\end{align*}

So we obtain a special case of [*Christmas Stocking Theorem*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChristmasStockingTheorem.html):

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)(k+2) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{k+2}{2} = 2 \binom{n+3}{3} = \frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}{3}. $$

Comment: but why lhs and rhs of my expression are equal?

Comment: @user7777777, No, they are *not* equal. If it is written in the solution book, then the book is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it like this:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(k+2) = \sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2+k = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n k = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Comment: And $\sum k^2=\cdots$?

Comment: there is a need to use derivetives

Answer (score 2):

Using the generalization proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/399213), and the substitutions
$$
\begin{align}
M&\mapsto n\\
m&\mapsto k\\
k&\mapsto 2\\
n&\mapsto 0
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)(k+2)
&=2\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+2}{2}\binom{n-k}{0}\\
&=2\binom{n+3}{3}
\end{align}
$$

---

**An Alternate Approach**

The recursive definition of the Pascal Triangle says that
$$
\binom{k+2}{2}=\binom{k+3}{3}-\binom{k+2}{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)(k+2)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n2\binom{k+2}{2}\\
&=2\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+3}{3}-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+2}{3}\right]\\
&=2\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+3}{3}-\sum_{k=-1}^{n-1}\binom{k+3}{3}\right]\\
&=2\left[\binom{n+3}{3}-\binom{2}{3}\right]\\
&=2\binom{n+3}{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(k+2) = \sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2+k=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left(\frac{2n+1}{3}+1\right)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{2n+4}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

By induction it can easily be shown that: $$\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$ This for $r=0,1,2,\dots$

For $r=2$ this results in: $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(k-1\right)k=\frac{1}{6}\left(n-1\right)n\left(n+1\right)$$
or equivalently: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(k+1\right)\left(k+2\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right)$$