# Combinatorial Identity with Binomial Coefficients: $ {{a+b+c-1}\choose c} = \sum_{i+j=c} {{a+i-1}\choose i}{{b+j-1}\choose j} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I got the following identity from commutative algebra.

I am curious to see elegant elementary methods.

> $$ {{a+b+c-1}\choose c} = \sum_{i+j=c} {{a+i-1}\choose i}{{b+j-1}\choose j} $$

Comment: Consider $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^a} \frac{1}{(1-z)^b} = \frac{1}{(1-z)^{a+b}}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a case of Vandermonde's identity.

The LHS is the coefficient of $x^c$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+b}}$, by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

On the other hand, $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+b}}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x)^b}$, hence:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \binom{a+b+c-1}{c}=[x^c]\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+b}}&=&\sum_{d=0}^{c}[x^d]\frac{1}{(1-x)^a}\cdot [x^{c-d}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^b}\\ &=& \sum_{i+j=c}\binom{a+i-1}{i}\binom{b+j-1}{j}, \end{eqnarray*}$$
as wanted.

Comment: (+1). Did you see my comment?

Comment: Hi @MarkoRiedel: I saw your comment when I was writing my answer, we came almost at the same time :)

Comment: *It is just a case of Vandermonde's identity.* - You sound just like a politician trying to calm the public and prevent mass hysteria in times of imminent danger... :-$)$

Answer (score 2):

For variety's sake here is a slightly different approach.
Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$\sum_{k=0}^c {k+a-1\choose a-1} {b-1+c-k\choose b-1}.$$

Introduce
$${b-1+c-k\choose b-1} = {b-1+c-k\choose c-k} = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{c-k+1}} (1+z)^{b-1+c-k} \; dz.$$

Observe  that this  is zero  when $k\gt  c$ so  we may  extend  $k$ to
infinity to get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{c+1}} (1+z)^{b-1+c} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} {k+a-1\choose a-1} \frac{z^k}{(1+z)^k}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{c+1}} (1+z)^{b-1+c} 
\frac{1}{(1-z/(1+z))^a}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{c+1}} (1+z)^{a+b-1+c} 
\frac{1}{(1+z-z)^a}
\; dz
\\ = {a+b+c-1\choose c}.$$

We can take $\epsilon \lt 1/2$ for the series to converge.

Comment: (+1) I appreciate different approaches, and although this works on the coefficients of $(1+z)^{-k}$, residues is a nice method of computation.

Comment: I often answer questions like this one using the Egorychev method which has the advantage that it includes very simple problem instances (see above) yet it can be extended to compute rather complicated binomial sums. A simple example might encourage the reader to try the method on more challenging ones involving convolutions of several binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Using the identity
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n-j}{k}\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{k+m+1}
$$
proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/399213), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i+j=c}\binom{a+i-1}{i}\binom{b+j-1}{j}
&=\sum_{i+j=c}\binom{a+i-1}{a-1}\binom{b+j-1}{b-1}\\
&=\binom{a+b+c-1}{a+b-1}\\
&=\binom{a+b+c-1}{c}\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as
$$\binom{a+b+c-1}{a+b-1} = \sum_{i=0}^c \binom{a+i-1}{a-1}\binom{b+c-i-1}{b-1},$$
which we can prove combinatorially by counting the number of $(a+b-1)$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,a+b+c-1\}$ in two different ways.  The LHS is clear.  To obtain the RHS, condition on the $a$th smallest element $a+i$.  Then we must choose $a-1$ smaller elements from $\{1,\dots,a+i-1\}$ and the remaining $b-1$ larger elements from $\{a+i+1,\dots,a+b+c-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, Marko Riedel's comment above.
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{\substack{i+j=c\\i\ge 0,j\ge 0}}\binom{a+i-1}{i}\binom{b+j-1}{j}
&=\sum_{\substack{i+j=c\\i\ge 0,j\ge 0}}(-1)^i\binom{-a}{i}(-1)^j\binom{-b}{j}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{i+j=c\\i\ge 0,j\ge 0}}(-1)^{i+j}\binom{-a}{i}\binom{-b}{j}\\
&=(-1)^c\binom{-a-b}{c}=\binom{a+b+c-1}{c}
\end{split}
$$