# combinatorial Sums

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know what the result of the following sum is

$\displaystyle\sum_{v_1+v_2=v}\binom{u+v_1-1}{u-1}\binom{w+v_2-1}{w-1}$

where $u>0$, $v>0$, $w>0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: see one of the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591041/combinatorial-identity-with-binomial-coefficients-abc-1-choose-c-sum?noredirect=1

Comment: I used some identities, but I had a mistake. Thank you for the information.