# Sum of binomial coefficients when lower suffices is same in the series: ${m \choose m}+{m+1 \choose m}+{m+2 \choose m}+...+{n \choose m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to find out sum of the following series:
$${m \choose m}+{m+1 \choose m}+{m+2 \choose m}+...+{n \choose m}$$
**My try**:
${m \choose m}+{m+1 \choose m}+{m+2 \choose m}+...+{n \choose m}$ = Coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^m + (1+x)^{m+1} + ... + (1+x)^n$

 Or, Coefficient of $x^m$
$$\frac{(1+x)^{m}((1+x)^{n}-1)}{1+x-1}$$
$$=\frac{(1+x)^{m+n}-(1+x)^{m}}{x}$$
But, how to proceed further?

**Note:** $m≤n$

Comment: You made a mistake, result you should obtain is  $(1+x)^m + (1+x)^{m+1} + ... + (1+x)^n=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^m}{x}$. Then, you can conclude that coefficient of $x^m$ is ${n+1 \choose m+1}$

Comment: @alans I used the sum of a GP formula. Can you tell me exactly where am I going wrong?

Comment: I hope that the following will make it clear: $$(1+x)^m + (1+x)^{m+1} + ... + (1+x)^n=(1+x)^m(1+(1+x)+\cdots+(1+x)^{n-m})=(1+x)^m\frac{(1+x)^{n-m+1}-1}{1+x-1}=(1+x)^m\frac{(1+x)^{n-m+1}-1}{x}=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^m}{x}$$

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate your help.

Comment: See also [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1490794) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1490794).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Other way**
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   k  \\
   m  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   k+1  \\
   m+1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)-\left( \begin{matrix}
   k  \\
   m+1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   k  \\
   m  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}\left[{\left( \begin{matrix}
   k+1  \\
   m+1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)-\left( \begin{matrix}
   k  \\
   m+1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}\right]=\left( \begin{matrix}
   n+1  \\
   m+1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
 **Also**

Let $x_i\in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_{k+2}=n+2$$

Comment: I was so close... Well thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $x^m$ in
$$\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^{m}}{x}$$
is obviously equal to the coefficient of $x^{m+1}$ in 
$$(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^{m}$$
which is nothing but
$${n+1\choose m+1},$$
as $n\geq m$ and the second term has degree $m<m+1$ and so gives no contribution.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^n
\end{align*}

> We obtain for $0\leq m \leq n$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{k}{m}
> &=\sum_{k=m}^n[x^m](1+x)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^m]\sum_{k=m}^n(1+x)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^m]\frac{(1+x)^{m}-(1+x)^{n+1}}{-x}\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^{m+1}]\left((1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^{m}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{n+1}{m+1}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (3) we use the *[finite geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Generalized_formula)*.
- In (4) we do some simplifications and  we also  use  the  rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^{p+q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^{-q}A(x)
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^{m+1}$ and observe that $(1+x)^{m}$ has no contribution.