# Prove the identity $\sum_{j=n}^N {j\choose n}={N+1 \choose n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

I want a proof of the identity
$${n \choose n} + {n+1 \choose n} + {n+2\choose n} +\cdots + {N \choose n} = {N+1 \choose n+1}$$
where $N\geq n$, by algebraic or combinatoric methods.

Comment: The earlier question has a variety of answers; [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1490965/12042) is a combinatorial argument.

Comment: In case its not clear why this post is a duplicate, note that yours is $\sum\limits_{t=n}^N\binom{t}{n} = 0+\sum\limits_{t=n}^N\binom{t}{n}=\sum\limits_{t=0}^N\binom{t}{n}$ since $\binom{t}{n}=0$ whenever $t<n$