# Prove that $\left(\!\!\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{k}\!\!\right)=\sum_{i=0}^k \left(\!\!\binom{n-1\vphantom{1}}{i}\!\!\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers. Prove that: $$\left(\!\!\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{k}\!\!\right)=\sum_{i=0}^k\left( \binom{n-1\vphantom{1}}{i}\right)$$

Edit: This is asking for a direct proof. Sorry if it is unclear, it's exactly what was asked of me in the quiz and I want to be sure I get it right! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Since

$$\left(\!\!\binom{n}k\!\!\right)=\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$$

by a [stars and bars argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), it’s an immediate consequence of the [hockey stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1k1).