# Evaluate the sum $1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+\dots+n\cdot (n+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to get the closed form of $1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+\dots+n\cdot (n+1)$
I do know the ans is $n(n+1)(n+2)/3$ but i have no idea of the steps.

Here are some of my scratch works:

1 II(2)

2 IIIIII(6) difference of 4

3 IIIIIIIIIIII(12) difference of 6

............. (the pattern of difference  observed is $2k$ for $k$ is 1 to $n$)

n IIIIIIII...........IIIIIII($n(n+1)$)

so i have Sum down vertical :

$$= 2n + 4(n-1) + 6(n-2) + ... +2n(n-(n-1))$$

after some simplify and grouping ,i got this:

$$2{ n\cdot n\cdot (n+1)/2 - (2+6+12+20+...+2n)}$$

I can't see i can get to the final result.

Great thanks for helping me out.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By indeterminate coefficients**:

$S_n$ will be of the form $an^3+bn^2+cn+d$. Then solve for $S_0=0,S_1=2,S_2=8,S_3=22.$

---

It's even easier to start from

$$S_n-S_{n-1}=n(n+1)=a(3n^2-3n+1)+b(2n-1)+c$$ and identify the powers, giving

$$3a=1,-3a+2b=1,a+b-c=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

We have that
$$1\cdot 2+2\cdot3+3\cdot 4+\dots+n\cdot(n+1)=2\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\binom{k}{2}=2\binom{n+2}{3}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{3}.$$
where we used the [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1k1)

Answer (score 2):

Take the finite geometric series $1 + x + x^2 + \ldots +x^{n+1} = \frac{x^{n+2}-1}{x-1}$. Now differentiate both sides two times and take the limit $x \to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways. Induction is probably the easiest. I think there's a way which involves assembling little cubes into a cuboid $n \times (n+1) \times (n+2)$, but that's basically just induction again and my drawing skills aren't good enough. (There might be an even more magic way which isn't fundamentally some kind of induction, but I don't see it.)

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: "Use induction"? Sure, I don't see why not.

Comment: How about "Use mathematics"?

Comment: "Mathematics" is not a specific proof technique. "Induction" is. The OP's question makes me suspect they have not considered induction, and it is undoubtedly an easy way to attack the question (if you don't already know RobertZ's binomial coefficient sum).