# how do I prove this formula combinatorially?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$$\binom{r}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r}+\binom{r+2}{r}+...+\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

I know how to prove this by induction.

But I got stuck with proving it combinatorially.

How do I start? and please give some directions.

Comment: Search the site for *hockey stick identity*. Most proofs probably use induction, but there may be combinatorial arguments also.

Comment: I actually came up with a combinatorial way of proving this. But that solution has already appeared [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1491698/11619), so I won't waste bandwidth by reposting it.

Comment: Actually scrolling further down the list of answers gives you [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1490965/11619). The same idea but more verbose.