# proof of $\sum_{i=k}^n {i \choose k}= {{n+1}\choose {k+1}}$ with another formula

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

I'm on an exercise for the university and have no clue what to do.
The exercise is the following:
You should proof that $\sum_{i=k}^n {i \choose k}= {{n+1}\choose {k+1}}$ . I've done that with an induction over $n$ and this goes very well.

But the other part is that we should use another formula an that is the following to proof it:

$$\sum_{i=k}^n {{i+1}\choose{k+1}} = \sum_{i=k}^n {i \choose{k+1}} + {i \choose{k}}$$

And there i need your help. Does anyone know what to do with this??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As for the content of what appears to actually be your question, $\binom{i+1}{k+1}=\binom{i}{k+1}+\binom{i}{k}$ is just [pascal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).  Rewritten, $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$, if you want to pick $r$ people from $n$ where one person is considered special, you may either pick the special person and $r-1$ additional people from the $n-1$ non-special people or you may choose not to pick the special person and instead pick all $r$ people from the $n-1$ not-special people

Comment: Once the statement is corrected, I expect that the identity you are attempting to prove is the [hockey stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1)

Comment: i will look that up! the first look seems very promising! thanks!