# Induction based on combinations and binomial theorem: ${}^nC_0+{}^{n+1}C_1+{}^{n+2}C_2+\dots+{}^{n+p}C_p={}^{n+p+1}C_p$

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I was looking at some questions in a Cambridge text and I reached this question however I am at it for 1 hr and can't seem to get the proof right. Any help ? 
[image: the question]

Comment: Did you try googling it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2832298/75923).

Comment: You can check [Simplify the expression $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n+k}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1871953) or [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1490794) and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1490794).

Answer (score 0):

Assume it true for $p-1$, i.e.
$${}^nC_0+{}^{n+1}C_1+{}^{n+2}C_2+\dots+{}^{n+p-1}C_{p-1}={}^{n+p}C_{p-1}$$
Let's prove it for $p$, i.e.
$${}^nC_0+{}^{n+1}C_1+{}^{n+2}C_2+\dots+{}^{n+p}C_p={}^{n+p+1}C_p$$
So the left hand side is composed of the assumption in the first equation plus ${}^{n+p}C_p$, i.e.
$${}^nC_0+{}^{n+1}C_1+{}^{n+2}C_2+\dots+{}^{n+p-1}C_{p-1}+{}^{n+p}C_p = {}^{n+p}C_{p-1} + {}^{n+p}C_{p}$$
By the addition property of combinations on the right hand side above, we get
$${}^nC_0+{}^{n+1}C_1+{}^{n+2}C_2+\dots+{}^{n+p-1}C_{p-1}+{}^{n+p}C_p ={}^{n+p+1}C_p$$