# binomial coefficient equal to sum

Tags: terminology, binomial-coefficients

I have observed the following relation

$$\binom{n}{k}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n-i-1}{k-i}, \quad \frac{n}2\leq k \leq n-1$$

Numerical example with $n=5$ and $k=3$

$$\binom{\color{red}5}{\color{blueviolet}3}= \binom{\color{Magenta}4}{\color{blueviolet}3}+\binom{\color{blueviolet}3}{\color{Orange}2}+\binom{\color{Orange}2}{\color{YellowGreen}1}+\binom{\color{YellowGreen}1}{\color{Brown}0}$$

$$10\  \ \  = \  \ \ 4 \ \  \ +\ \  \ 3 \ \  \ +  \  \ \  2  \  \  \ \ + \ \ 1$$

Is this relation true? If yes, is there a name for it?

I´ve used identities like $\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \binom nk + \binom n{k+1}$ to show the relation above, but I failed. Does anyone have an idea how to manage it?

Thanks for taking time to read the question.

Comment: It is an instance of the [hockeystick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity). For a proof of it see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2832298/75923).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See my comment on your question.

---

The hockeystick identity tells us that: $$\sum_{i=r}^{n}\binom{i}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

Applying this we find:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{n-i-1}{k-i}=\sum_{i=n-1-k}^{n-1}\binom{i}{n-1-k}=\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}$$

Answer (score 6):

This can also be shown with negative binomial coefficients and Vandermonde's Identity:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n-i-1}{k-i}
&=\sum_i\binom{n-i-1}{k-i}\binom{i}{i}\tag1\\
&=\sum_i\binom{k-n}{k-i}(-1)^{k-i}\binom{-1}{i}(-1)^i\tag2\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{k-n-1}{k}\tag3\\[3pt]
&=\binom{n}{k}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: remove the limits from the summation
$(2)$: [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$(3)$: [Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(4)$: negative binomial coefficients

Comment: Finally I found that $\binom{i}{i}=\binom{-1}{i}(-1)^i$ also uses negative binomial coefficients. I always learn a lot from your answer!

Comment: @FtyRain: Indeed. In $(7)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516), I state $\binom{-1}{i}=(-1)^i[i\ge0]$, and of course, $\binom{i}{i}=[i\ge0]$.