# How to mathematically prove: $\sum_{x = r}^{n} C(x , r) = C(n+1 , r+1)$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

The RHS is equal to the number of ways of selecting $r+1$ out of $n+1$ objects. 
If I sum the number of selections when the $(r+1)$th (i.e. the last) selection is the at the $(x+1)$th position, I get the RHS.

I verified it with some values but couldn't prove it mathematically.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Check out various proofs here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1)

Answer (score 1):

The usual notation is $\sum_{x=r}^n\binom{x}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$. Since $\binom{x}{r}=\binom{x+1}{r+1}-\binom{x}{r+1}$, the sum telescopes to $\binom{n+1}{r+1}-\binom{r}{r+1}$. But the last term is, of course, $0$.