# Prove formula by combinatorially

Tags: combinatorial-proofs

> $$ \binom{r}{r} + \binom{r+1}{r}+\binom{r+2}{r} + \cdots + \binom{n}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

I knew that I had to prove from RHS and LHS
RHS simply like: take $r+1$ out of $n+1$ elements
But How can I write about LHS?

Comment: use the combinatorics formula: $\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}$

Comment: @user29418 can you give more details?

Comment: $\frac{r!}{0!r!} + \frac{(r+1)!}{1!r!} + ...$, let $n=r, r=r$ for the first one; $n=r+1, r=r$ for the second one, etc. At that point it's all algebra.

Comment: For an algebraic argument, first expand out the binomials and cancel out factorials. The formula for $\binom nr = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ is given above.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In choosing $r+1$ of elements $1,2,\dots,n+1,$ suppose the the last element we choose is element $k.$ where $r+1\leq k\leq n+1.$  Then we must choose $r$ of the preceding $k-1$ elements.  The total number of ways to do this is the sum on the left-hand side.