# Sum of factorial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem

How do we find the sum of this series
$$ \sum_{i=n}^m \binom{i}{r} $$
where,   $r<n<m$

Comment: Related: [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n\binom{t}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1).

Comment: Rewrite your sum as $\sum\limits_{i=n}^m\binom{i}{r} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m\binom{i}{r} - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{i}{r}$ and apply the hockey stick identity twice to get $\binom{m+1}{r+1}-\binom{n}{r+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I was a expecting a boring long algebraic proof but this hockey stick identify was unexpectedly clever