# Simplifying ${ n \choose k } + { n-1 \choose k-1 } + \dots + { n-k \choose 0 }$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Given $k \leq n$ positive integers, how to simplify ${ n \choose k } + { n-1 \choose k-1 } + \dots + { n-k \choose 0 }$?

Comment: ${5 \choose 2}+{4 \choose 1}+{3 \choose 0} = 10+4+1 = 15$  rather than $17$.  Look at Pascal's triangle to recognise your results. $ { n \choose k } + { n-1 \choose k-1 } + \dots + { n-k \choose 0 } = { n+1 \choose k }$

Comment: this is probably provable by induction

Comment: Indeed very simple. Thank you.

Comment: The induction step is ${ n+1 \choose k+1 } +{ n \choose k } + { n-1 \choose k-1 } + \dots + { n-k \choose 0 } = { n+1 \choose k+1 }+ { n+1 \choose k } = { n +2\choose k +1}$

Comment: *"This seems to have binomial-coefficient-like behavior, but I can't figure the exact form. "* That made my day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\binom{n+1}{k}-\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}$$
$$\binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\binom{n-1}{k-2}$$
$$\binom{n-1}{k-2}-\binom{n-2}{k-2}=\binom{n-2}{k-3}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\binom{n-k+2}{1}-\binom{n-k+1}{1}=\binom{n-k+1}{0}$$
$$\binom{n-k+1}{0}-\binom{n-k}{0}=1-1=0$$

Summing we get $$\binom{n+1}{k}-\left(\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-2}{k-2}+\cdots+\binom{n-k}{0}\right)=0$$

Hence simpler form for your expression is $\binom{n+1}{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Applying symmetry twice and the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n-k+j}{j} = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n-k+j}{n-k} = \binom{n+1}{n-k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k}$$