# Reduce summation to expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory

I am working on a probability problem and ran across the following sum...

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} {n-i\choose r} $$

where $k$ is some arbitrary positive integer such that $k \le n-r-1$.

is there a simple, compact expression/formula for it?

I noticed that the expansion consists of pairs of terms that *almost* permit the application of Pascal's rule, but the terms are all positive so this is not an option.

I am also aware of the hockey stick identity mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-zhu-shijie-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk), which would be useful if the sum was from $i=1,2,...,k,...n-r-1$, but the sum is only over terms up to some arbitrary $k$.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Write it as 
$$
\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{i}r\right]-
\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-k-1}\binom{i}r\right],$$ then use the [hockey stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-zhu-shijie-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk).