# Does summing over even upper indexes of a binomial have a closed form? $\sum_{0 \le i < n} \binom{2i}{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

The even and odd sums can be determined from each other:

$$\sum_{0 \le i < n} \binom{2i}{k} + \sum_{0 \le i < n} \binom{2i+1}{k} = \binom{2n}{k + 1}$$

Comment: $\sum_{0 \le i < n} \binom{2i}{k} + \sum_{0 \le i < n} \binom{2i+1}{k} = \sum_{0 \le i \le 2n-1} \binom{i}{k}$

Comment: @Bumblebee Your right-hand side plus the hockey-stick identity yields $\binom{2n}{k+1}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of the hockey stick/Zhu Shijie identity $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-zhu-shijie-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk)

Comment: @Bumblebee no. The hockey stick identity can be used for a sum over *all* upper indices, but not over only even or only odd indices