# Simplify and Prove the identity $\sum_{j=k}^n \binom jk = \binom{n + 1}{k + 1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove it by algebra.[Reference](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5Bj%20choose%20k%2C%7Bj%2Ck%2Cn%7D%5D)

What i tried so far is to simplify the binomials and cancelling similar variables.
I stuck at some point without any clue on this step :

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=k}^n \binom{j}{k} & = \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{j!}{k!(j-k)!} & \text{[using the formula for binomial(j, k)]}\\
& = \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{j(j-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (k+1)k!}{k!(j-k)!} & \text{[writing out the factorial]}
\end{align*}

I would like for an help to understand if there is any simple way to prove this identity.

Comment: "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The lower index SHOULD BE ZERO for the identity to hold. That is "j=0" not "j=k".

Comment: that's equivalent to j=k as you can see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-zhu-shijie-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk